# Why are there two cases for the proof of the dimension theorem on Wikipedia?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me to understand why the proof of the dimension theorem for vector spaces at

[https://en.wikipedia.orgwikiDimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces][1]

has two cases. Why does the proof of the first case (where the index set I is an infinite set) not also apply to the second case (where I is a finite set).

Using the notation in the proof, it seems to me in either case card(I) > card(union E_j) since card(J) >= card(union E_j) where each E_j is a finite subset of I for each j of J.

Under the assumption card(I) > card(J) we then have the contradiction in the first case of the proof whether I is an infinite set or a finite set.

What am I missing?

Updating the link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces

Comment: The link is invalid.

Comment: Because if $I$ is finite it is possible that that union is equal to $I$ and you need it to miss something.

Comment: The article already mentions that in the infinite dimensional case some weak choice principle is required but this is not necessary in the finite dimensional case. People like to separate proofs needing choice from those that don't.

Answer (score 1):

Using the notation from the proof:

If $|I|>|J|$, then no union over finite subsets of $J$ can cover $I$. For example, since both sets are infinite, if $J$ is countable then $I$ must be uncountable. However, a countable union of countable sets is countable, so there will always be an element of $I$ that is not covered by the union over finite subsets of $J$.